# Highlight keyword on search results php

Tags: php, highlight

I am trying to make any keyword bold when the user types the current keyword.

I have this code and it is working fine.

```
for($k=$no_words; $k>0 ;$k--) {

            $w=trim($search_array[$k-1]);
            if($w!='')
            {
                $result[$i]['title'] = preg_replace('/(' . preg_quote($search_array[$k-1], '/') . ')/siU', '<b>\\1</b>', $result[$i]['title']);
                $result[$i]['description'] = preg_replace('/(' . preg_quote($search_array[$k-1], '/') . ')/siU', '<b>\\1</b>', $result[$i]['description']);
            }
        }
```

My problem is as follows:

I have this keyword: **this is my keyword**

When I type: " this is my keyword " I get this result:  "**this is my keyword**"

But when I type: " This is keyword " I get this result: "this is my keyword" without the words in the result being bolded.

What I doing wrong?

Comment: there is no substring "this is keyword" in string "this is _my_ keyword"

Comment: and what i need to do in this code?

Comment: what is in `$search_array`?

Comment: $search_array = explode('%20', $search);
   $no_words = count($search_array);

Comment: what is in `$search`?

Comment: $search = str_replace("(", "\(", $search);
   $search = str_replace(")", "\)", $search);

Comment: All together : if($search) {

      $search = str_replace("(", "\(", $search);
   $search = str_replace(")", "\)", $search);

   $search_array = explode('%20', $search);
   $no_words = count($search_array);

  } else $no_words = 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you need following:

```
$search_array = array_unique(explode(' ', $search));
foreach ($search_array as $k => $v)
{
    $w = trim($v);
    if ($w)
    {
        $result[$i]['title'] = preg_replace('/(' . preg_quote($w, '/') . ')/siU', '<b>\\1</b>', $result[$i]['title']);
        $result[$i]['description'] = preg_replace('/(' . preg_quote($w, '/') . ')/siU', '<b>\\1</b>', $result[$i]['description']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Lashane if i type this is my  keyword with to spaces it's dont take any results you now how fix that?

Comment: two spaces in my__keyword

Comment: @user3673602 no, I cannot see through walls

Comment: Can send you my code? and i want tell you and something good please

Comment: @user3673602 just read rules of this site, and post another question with proper example/description